# Read a string in dictionary values and replace a specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, replace

I have a dict in which each value is a string. In some values, this string has "-" that I would like to remove. I have been told that it is not possible to replace the values of a dict. Is that right?

```py
mydict

'GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:': '-TRAEKEAIIQELKEKFKEARVAVLADYRGLNV-------AEATRLRRRLREAGCEFKVAKNTLTGLAARQAGLE-----GLDPYLEGPIAIAFG-VDPVAPAKVLSDF--',
```

I would wish something like

```py
mydict

'GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:': 'TRAEKEAIIQELKEKFKEARVAVLADYRGLNVAEATRLRRRLREAGCEFKVAKNTLTGLAARQAGLEGLDPYLEGPIAIAFGVDPVAPAKVLSDF',
```

Comment: The values are mutable, meaning they can be replaced. It's the keys that are immutable, meaning they can't be replaced. So yes, you can replace the values like you are wanting to do

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I'm not sure what you mean by that. You *can* replace keys, in the sense that you can remove them, and then add a new one.

Comment: Sorry I should have said modified, not replaced. The keys have to be removed/added to be changed, but they can't directly be altered without doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutly you can, just iterate over the mappings key/value, and change the associated value by the processed one

```
d = {'superkey': "foo--bar", 'superkey2': "--foo--bar",
     'GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:': '-TRAEKEAIIQELKEKFKEARVAVLADYRGLNV-------AEATRLRRRLREAGCEFKVAKNTLTGLAARQAGLE-----GLDPYLEGPIAIAFG-VDPVAPAKVLSDF--', }

# LOOP version
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = v.replace("-", "")

# DICT COMPREHENSION version
d = {k: v.replace("-", "") for k, v in d.items()}

print(d)  # {'superkey': 'foobar', 'superkey2': 'foobar', 
             'GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:': 'TRAEKEAIIQELKEKFKEARVAVLADYRGLNVAEATRLRRRLREAGCEFKVAKNTLTGLAARQAGLEGLDPYLEGPIAIAFGVDPVAPAKVLSDF'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can simply use

```
mydict['GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:'] = mydict['GCA_000010565.1_genomic    Ribosomal_L10:'].replace("-","")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you've been told BS. The solution:

```
for k in mydict:
     mydict[k] = mydict[k].replace('-', '')
```